# Removing Drop down of cache from input text element

Tags: php, javascript, html

This kind of question may be asked several times but my problem is different.

I have a Text field and its declaration is like this

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="email" id="email" value="Email" onfocus="if (this.value=='Email') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Email';" onkeyup="javascript:chk_email(this.value);" onblur="javascript:chk_email(this.value);" />
```

When I enter a word a drop down of all similar cache email is coming below the textbox.

I try with adding `autocomplete="off"` in `input` tag still it is coming.

I also write this javascript but no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("email").reset();
</script>
```

Is there any way I can remove this drop down of cache email from my form. I only want to remove only this textbox's cache not the whole forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`autocomplete="off"` is not valid markup with XHTML Transitional, which is a common DOCTYPE

try

**jQuery**

```
$("#email").attr("autocomplete","off");
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("email").setAttribute("autocomplete","off");
```

Let me know if this help or not.

Comment: thanks for answer. but it is not helpfull. the drop down still coming.

Comment: may you post your code and tell me which browser you are checking?

Comment: i have posted enough code for view. And i am using `Firefox`.

Comment: yes, but thats not enough to trace the exact error as this option should work in normal condition, so just wanted to see the html/js or you can create fiddle and show me (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 2):

How about using `<textarea>` instead of `<input>`. It will work sure as `<textarea>` won't show drop-down. See code

```
<textarea  autocomplete="off" name="email" id="email"  onfocus="if (this.value=='Email') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Email';" onkeyup="javascript:chk_email(this.value);" onblur="javascript:chk_email(this.value);" rows="1" >
value here</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead Of adding `autocomplete="off"` to input tag try adding that to form tag

```
<form name="myform" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: i have written this `I only want to remove only this textbox's cache not the whole forms.` see the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of input type text use input type email

```
<input type="email" autocomplete="off" name="email" id="email" value="Email" onfocus="if (this.value=='Email') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Email';" onkeyup="javascript:chk_email(this.value);" onblur="javascript:chk_email(this.value);" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to change the name of the input element in question.

```
document.getElementById("email").name = Math.random();
```

This will give the element a completely new name each time and the browser wont recognise it as an email input thus wont display the cache.

This has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following variables:

```
// Older browsers
onCopy=”return false”
onPaste=”return false”
onDrag=”return false”
onDrop=”return false”

autocomplete="off" // HTML 5
```

Answer (score 1):

The autcomplete=off options is not standard, but you can use it in most browsers and it should work, but not as an input attribute, rather the form it belongs to:

```
<form ... autocomplete="off">
    # your inputs
</form>
```

Although that is more a client issue rather than an application one. More on this here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

Comment: be aware of the part in the documentation where it states that the property will be ignored in "name" and "address" parameters case. Also read about the workaround for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

declare document type as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

since `autocomplete=”off”` is not valid markup with XHTML Transitional, 
which is a common DOCTYPE

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with cache, so i cleared whole cache from browser and used the html which i was using

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="email" id="email" value="Email" onfocus="if (this.value=='Email') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Email';" onkeyup="javascript:chk_email(this.value);" onblur="javascript:chk_email(this.value);" />
```